# SQL - Joining together summed data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, query-performance, subquery

I've been having the following problem for days. I've kinda managed to resolve it, but the performance is what bothers me.

Basically I have one table of persons, and two tables (`debt` and `wealth`) with references to `person`. `debt`/`wealth` tables can have multiple rows that refer to same `personID`.

I would need an outcome where I would simply have all the persons listed with summed debt and wealth as own columns.

**First let me represent the tables I have:**

Table 'person':

```
| ID | name    |
|----|---------|
|  1 | Adam    |
|  2 | Berg    |
|  3 | Carl    |
|  4 | David   |
```

Table 'wealth':

```
| ID | personID | value    |
|----|----------|----------|
|  1 |  1       |  100     |
|  2 |  1       |  2000    |
|  3 |  2       |  30000   |
|  4 |  3       |  400000  |
|  5 |  3       |  5000000 |
```

Table 'debt':

```
| ID | personID | value    |
|----|----------|----------|
|  1 |  1       |  100     |
|  2 |  1       |  2000    |
|  3 |  2       |  30000   |
|  4 |  2       |  400000  |
|  5 |  3       |  5000000 |
```

**Expected result:**

```
| personID | debtSum | wealthSum |
|----------|---------|-----------|
|  1       |    2100 |      2100 |
|  2       |   30000 |    430000 |
|  3       | 5400000 |   5000000 |
|  4       |  (null) |    (null) |
```

**My solution:**

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f4d7/1/0)</kbd>

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE p.ID, debtSum, wealthSum
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT personID, SUM(value) AS debtSum FROM debt GROUP BY personID) AS d ON d.personID = p.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT personID, SUM(value) AS wealthSum FROM wealth GROUP BY personID) AS w ON w.personID = p.ID
```

This query returns the correct data, but as I said, the performance worries me. For example if I have added thousands of rows inside debt table for a person which doesn't exist (e.g. with personID = 5), it takes much longer to execute the query. I guess it does sum up the all data for that person as well, though it is not needed for the result?

I'm using SQL Server 2008, though the <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f4d7/1/0)</kbd> is using MySQL (if that makes a difference).

**I'd appreciate tips on how to improve the performance of the query. I'm running out of ideas.**

Comment: What fiddle? And if you create a sql fiddle it should be for sql server since that is what you are using.

Comment: Can you post your query plan or a picture of it?  <CTRL> + L in SSMS...

Comment: You have the correct query. If you have a problem then it's probably indexing.

Comment: You query is probably already the best possible as both current answers will not return correct SUMs. Regarding your worries about rows with a non-existing `PersonID`, this should hardly happen if you got correct data and even if performance should still be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's how I would do it, though I'd wager proper indexes will have a bigger impact on performance than query structure:

**EDIT POST COMMENTS:**

```
SELECT ID, SUM(debtSum) AS debtSum, SUM(wealthSum) AS wealthSum
FROM (
SELECT p.ID, d.value AS debtSum, NULL AS wealthSum
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN debt d ON d.personID = p.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT p.ID, NULL AS debtSum, w.Value AS wealthSum
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN wealth w ON w.personID = p.ID
) t
GROUP BY t.ID
```

You should have indexes on Person.Id, Debt.PersonID, and Wealth.PersonID

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but wouldn't this cause the `wealthSum` to be calculated wrong for `personID` = 3. Because due to left joins `personID` 3 has `wealth` value saved twice.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "calculated wrong".   What do you think the result would be that you would consider wrong?

Comment: @turnips - I very much doubt indices are necessary, because the joins already are foreign key - primary key relations.

Comment: @avk - covering indexes would prevent table scans.  Why would an index not help?

Comment: @CDC, because most RDBMS are intelligent enough to include an index when a primary key in a table is referenced.

Comment: Not really.  You have to manually create indexes.  For example, if all tables had 100 columns, if you had non-clustered indexes that covered all of your columns, you could reduce your reads by 100-fold, for example.

Comment: Query tuning is an art, IMO.  Here is a good article about what a covering index is and why you should care.  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/

Comment: @CDC - Thanks for the information. Always happy to learn new things. But I wonder how it reflects the foreign key - primary key solution offered in this particular answer, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: @turnips Ok, I guess you edited your first comment, because I was responding to a question about PersonID 4.   I see now that my query is returning doubled values due to the two-table join.   This can be avoided with a UNION.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman - Executing this query for the same data as on the first post gives me `wealthSum` of 10,000,000 where `personID` is 3 (instead of 5,000,000).

Indexing wouldn't prevent this, would it?

**Edit:** @TabAlleman - Yes, I mistakenly sent the comment too early. Damn you "Enter" key! :)

Comment: No indexing won't fix the wrong results, it will just get them faster.   : )   My edited answer should get the correct results.

Comment: Why should this be any faster than the original query?

Comment: @dnoeth, @TabAlleman - This definitely seems to be faster than my original query. In my test db with some 100k extra rows in `debt`, this query was executed in 0.0181 s. In comparison the original query took 0.4125 s. I guess this is due to that in the original query all the rows are summed regardless if they are used in the result or not.

Comment: @turnips: If there're actually rows with non-existing `personIds`
 you got a severe problem, don't you have Foreign Keys in your data model?

Comment: @dnoeth - I don't have non-existing ids in the production db. I only created ones for testing purposes. Why I was interested in performance is that I'll need to be able to give certain criteria for the query so that not all `persons` are always returned. This way was only to simulate this same situation without me having to generate large amounts of data in database. It seems that this answer is working better that the original, I will still validate it tomorrow in the real db.

Comment: @turnips: You should have said that from the beginning :-) You might also try Correlated Scalar Subqueries, e.g. `SELECT p.ID, (SELECT SUM(value) FROM debt AS d WHERE d.personID = p.ID) AS debtSum, ...
FROM person AS p`

Comment: I thought about a Subquery solution, like that proposed by @dnoeth, but I decided it wouldn't scale well for resultsets containing large numbers of Person.ID, since each subquery would be executed once for each row.   However, if you plan on mostly dealing in small resultsets, it might be pretty fast.

Comment: @TabAlleman: It's logically executed once per row, but a decent optimizer should be able to rewrite it more efficiently...